# Replacing elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with n occurrences of a certain element.  I have a second list with

```
 Length[lis2] = n
```

I would like to replace the nth occurrence of the certain element in lis1 with the nth member of lis2.

```
lis1 = {A,b,c,d,A,e,f,g} (* Here, A is the special character. *)
lis2 = {X,Y}

res = {X,b,c,d,Y,e,f,g}
```

It seems that there should be an easy way of placing the nth member of lis2 at the right place in lis1 using

```
Position[lis1,A]
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: `ReplacePart[lis1, 
 Thread[Flatten[Position[lis1, A]][[;; UpTo@Length@lis2]] -> lis2]]`  will get you started. You'll want to harden this with error checking (enough elements to change, etc) if this is not some one-shot need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lis1 = {A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g}
lis2 = {X, Y};

pos = Flatten @ Position[lis1, A];
lis1[[pos]] = lis2[[;; UpTo @ Length @ pos]];
lis1
```

> {X, b, c, d, Y, e, f, g}

You can also use `ReplaceAll` as follows:

```
lis1 = {A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g};

l = RotateLeft[lis2];
lis1 /. A :> First[l = RotateRight[l]]
```

> {X, b, c, d, Y, e, f, g}

```
l = RotateLeft[lis2];
lis1 /. e :> First[l = RotateRight[l]]
```

> {A, b, c, d, A, X, f, g}

Answer (score 3):

This one does seem to do the trick:

```
ReplacePart[lis1, Thread[Position[lis1, A][[All, 1]] -> lis2]]
```

I assume that all your inputs have proper length and structure. If thats not guaranteed you might want to incorporate some input checks or use different method altogether.

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g};

lb = {X, Y};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[lb &, la, Position[la, A]]
```

{X, b, c, d, Y, e, f, g}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g};

l2 = {X, Y};
```

Using `PositionIndex` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
rules = Reverse /@  Splice@*Thread /@ (Normal@PositionIndex[l1] /. A -> l2);

Values[Sort@rules]

(*{X, b, c, d, Y, e, f, g}*)
```

Comment: The `X` and `Y` don't show up in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @Syed! See the update, please. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `PositionIndex` and `ReplacePart`:**

In order to reduce the fragility of the solution, as many as possible replacements are made depending on the number of times the special character appears and while the replacements are available.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
replaceAMAP[alist_List, subs_List, char_] := Module[{min, pi},
  pi = PositionIndex[alist][char];
  min = Min[Length@pi, Length@subs];
  ReplacePart[alist, 
   Thread[PositionIndex[alist][char][[1 ;; min]] -> subs[[1 ;; min]]]]
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

```
replaceAMAP[{A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g}, Style[#, Red] & /@ {X, Y, Z}, A]
replaceAMAP[{A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g, A}, 
 Style[#, Red] & /@ {X, Y, P, Q}, A]
replaceAMAP[{A, b, c, d, A, e, f, g, A}, Style[#, Red] & /@ {X, Y}, A]
```

---

*Results:*

[image]